# Stop changes being delivered to a stream - RTC source control

Tags: clearcase, rtc

Is it possible to prevent users from delivering change sets to a stream ?

If I have a stream that is being actively developed on and want to stop changes being delivered to that stream after a certain date is it possible to just 'lock' the stream so it becomes read only ? I want to ensure no changes can sneak into a stream after a particular date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and change the ownership as well as the visibility of the stream, in order to set it to a team (which would exclude most of the members of the project area except a select few).

You can associate to that team the deliver right in the `process area / Team configuration / permissions` configuration section.
This is what [that thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/70421/how-to-lock-a-stream-or-component) alludes to.

Answer (score 1):

https://jazz.net/library/article/215 describe the different options.  There are read access patterns, write access permissions & preconditions on deliver which may help you depending on what you need exactly.

JohnC

Comment: +1. BUt I am still stuck with RTC3.0, and some of those features are "New in RTC 4.0" ;)

Comment: FYI Upgrade from 3.x to 4.x is a lot easier than 2.x to 3.x.  Minimal migration time, fewer steps.

Comment: Minimal migration time, fewer steps? Thousands of clients on several continents... The migration will be 6 months project, at best.

Comment: Upgrade instructions/webform @ http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/clmhelp/v4r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.jazz.install.doc%2Ftopics%2Froadmap_clm_upgrade.html   Additionally 4.x supports 3.x clients, so you can roll out clients incrementally. See http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/clmhelp/v4r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.jazz.install.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_upgrade_client_vs_eclipse.html

Comment: Excellent :) I have a meeting next week, to define and start that migration process. I will mention your comment ;)