# Restricting developers to deliver to stream based on team - good practice?

Tags: rtc

Reading an earlier question I asked about restricting developers from delivering to a stream :

[Stop changes being delivered to a stream - RTC source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345286/stop-changes-being-delivered-to-a-stream-rtc-source-control)

I think a solution to this is to create a new team area with just the developers that are required ownership of the stream. Change the ownership of the stream to this newly created team area. The developers of the newly created team area will then be only developers that can deliver to this stream. Will the developers that are no longer members of the team ownded by stream still be able to view the stream and its change sets ?

Is this good practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the developers that are no longer members of the team ownded by stream still be able to view the stream and its change sets ?

Yes. (unless, with RTC4, you set read access preventing others to read the content of your stream).

Is this good practice ?

Yes, although I am using it on an "integration" stream in order for an "integration" team to *accept* changes from other stream.
See for example "[**Restrict user access at component level within a stream**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518954/restrict-user-access-at-component-level-within-a-stream/10519357#10519357)".

In other word, I don't restrict deliver team by team, for every stream.
I restrict deliver only for certain key stream, and make sure only the team in charge of that stream can *accept* changes from any other stream, allowing said team to control exactly what is landing in their stream.

Comment: it seems (in my rtc setup) developers can deliver changes to any 'team area' as long as they are members of same 'project area'. Is there a setting in RTC that needs to be configured to prevent developers from delivering to stream in a 'team area' that they are not a member of ?

Comment: @user470184 Are you using RTC4 or RTC3: with RTC4, you have fine-grained level access (read or write) with https://jazz.net/library/article/215

Comment: im using RTC3, developers not being able to deliver to streams in different team area should be functionality 'out of the box' ?

Comment: in your link posted(jazz.net/library/article/215) details I can just select all of the components in given stream, change owner and ensure "Restrict to members of this team area and its child team areas" is checked, this will provide same restriction I think

Comment: @user470184 With RTC3, I have to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518954/restrict-user-access-at-component-level-within-a-stream/10519357#10519357 to fully restrict deliveries (because my components have to be modified by several teams)